# How can i disable load button on pdf reader in javaFx

Tags: button, javafx, disable

I created a pdf reader using boxPdf.
[image]
My project contain 4 java files and ui.fxml
 The main file (main.java)
 the controller (controller.java)
 display pdf file class (pdfDisplay.java)
 and the pdf model (pdfModel.java).
the load button is implemented on the controller.java, when i click on it i will load a pdf file with a close button.
[image: ![enter image description here]
My question is:
 
***How can i disable the load button, when a pdf is displayed, until when i click on the close button?***
 
Because as you can see, in the second picture, the load button is always enabled, and user can load another file even if the first one is displayed, what i don't want.

Another answer:
***When i close the pdf displayed, and load another one i get:
Children: duplicate children added: parent = AnchorPane[id=anchor, styleClass=root] in the debugger***
This is my code project
main.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *@author toru
 */
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ui.fxml"));
        parent.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Vet0b00k5");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(parent,600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
     }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

controller.java

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class controller{

     @FXML 
     private AnchorPane anchor = new AnchorPane();
     Button loadButton=new Button ("Load");
     pdfDisplay pdfFileOpened= new pdfDisplay();
     HBox menuLoadB = new HBox (1);
     Path Path;
     PdfModel model= new PdfModel();


    public void initialize(){

        /*this part doesn't work*/
        if(Path==null){
            loadButton.setDisable(false);
            }
            else{
            loadButton.setDisable(true);
            }
        /*this part doesn't work*/

        menuLoadB.getChildren().add(loadButton);
        anchor.getChildren().addAll(menuLoadB);
        loadButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                loadFile();

            }
        });

    }

 void loadFile() {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Upload File Path");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(

    new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PDF", "*.pdf"));
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(anchor.getScene().getWindow());

    if (file != null && file.toPath()!=null) {

        String f=file.getPath();
        pdfFileOpened.setModel(f);
        anchor.getChildren().addAll(pdfFileOpened.affichePDF());

    } else  {
        System.out.println("error"); // or something else
    }

 }
}
```

pdfDisplayClass.java

```
package application;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


public class pdfDisplay{


         Button xButton=new Button ("X");


         HBox menu = new HBox (1);

         Pagination pagination;
         Path Path;
         PdfModel model= new PdfModel();
         ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
         VBox vboxRoot= new VBox();
         ImageView imageView = new ImageView();



     public VBox createPage(int pageIndex) {


         VBox box = new VBox();
            imageView = new ImageView(model.getImage(pageIndex));
            imageView.setFitWidth(model.afficheLargeur()*1.25);
            imageView.setFitHeight(model.afficheHauteur()*1.25);

                VBox.setMargin(scrollPane, new Insets(10, 50, 10, 50));
                scrollPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(vboxRoot.heightProperty());
                scrollPane.setPannable(true);
                scrollPane.setContent(imageView);
                scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
                scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
                scrollPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;");

                pagination.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");
                box.getChildren().add(scrollPane);

                return box;
        }
     void setModel(String f) {
            model= new PdfModel(Paths.get(f));
     }
     Path getModel() {

            return model.getPath();
     }
     VBox affichePDF() {

            pagination = new Pagination();
            pagination.setPageCount(model.nombreDePages());
            pagination.setPageFactory((Integer pageIndex) -> { return createPage(pageIndex);});



            xButtonAction();
           VBox.setMargin(pagination, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
            VBox.setMargin(menu, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

            menu.getChildren().addAll(xButton);
            menu.setStyle("-fx-border-color:yellow;");
            vboxRoot.setStyle("-fx-border-color:yellow;");
            vboxRoot.getChildren().addAll(menu,pagination);

            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(vboxRoot, 50.0);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(vboxRoot, 10.0);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(vboxRoot, 40.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(vboxRoot, 40.0);

           return vboxRoot;
        }

     void xButtonAction() {

         xButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                    fermerFichier();
                }
            });

     }

     void fermerFichier() {
            pagination.setPageFactory( (Integer pageIndex) -> { return null;} );
            menu.getChildren().removeAll(xButton);
            vboxRoot.getChildren().removeAll(menu,pagination);
            model.setPath(null);
            model.fermer();

        }

}
```

pdfmodel.java

```
package application;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
//import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;

/**
 * @author toru
 */
class PdfModel {
    //private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PdfModel.class.getName());

    private PDDocument document;
    private PDFRenderer renderer;

    Path chemin;

    PdfModel() {

    }

    PdfModel(Path path) {
        try {
            chemin=path;
            document = PDDocument.load(path.toFile());
            renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException("PDDocument thorws IOException file=" + path, ex);
        }
    }

    int nombreDePages() {
        return document.getPages().getCount();
    } 



    void fermer() {
        try {
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void setPath(Path pPays)
      {
       chemin = pPays;
      }

    Path getPath()
      {
       return chemin;
      }



double afficheHauteur() {

        PDPage page = document.getPage(document.getNumberOfPages() - 1);
         PDRectangle pageSize = page.getMediaBox();

         return pageSize.getHeight();

    }

   double afficheLargeur() {

        PDPage page = document.getPage(document.getNumberOfPages() - 1);
         PDRectangle pageSize = page.getMediaBox();

         return pageSize.getWidth();


    }
    Image getImage(int pageNumber) {
        BufferedImage pageImage;

        try {
            pageImage = renderer.renderImage(pageNumber,3);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException("PDFRenderer throws IOException", ex);
        }
        return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(pageImage, null);

    }

}
```

ui.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="anchor" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.controller">
   <children>
      <HBox prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

You can download [my eclipse project](http://veto-constantine.com/vetobooksone.rar) and [the pdf box](http://veto-constantine.com/pdfbox-app-2.0.19.jar)

thanks for taking the time to read all of this

best regards

Comment: _Sorry if my code is not compliant, I am not a professional programmer_ - doesn't matter: if you want help from anybody you have to make it as easy as possible for __them__ to answer __your__ question. First step is to stick to java naming conventions and try hard to get the code fomatting right. Anyway, without a [mcve], there's no way to do your debugging for you. So go ahead and write such an example, will give you a little practice at worst and let you solve the problem yourself at best :)

Comment: btw, this is not related to pdf - it's plain logic: disable the button after loading, enable it again on another trigger (f.i. after saving)

Comment: @Kleopatra thanks for your advises, i updated my post, i hope that's more clear

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is the solution.

The loadButton must be static.

To access controller loadButton from another class and set it to ennable, this is the correct command

```
application.controller.loadButton.setDisable(false);
```

regards

Comment: what does it means??

Comment: ... wrong (sry, mobile hick-up ;) don't use static scope

Comment: how can i do that in other way??